# React native: Device has no app to handle URI

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm new to react native. I'm familiar with react.

I'm using Expo. Running npm start and then running iOS simulator from the menu has been working just fine until recently. When running npm start, console prints something like:

```
Metro waiting on exp+jorato://expo-development-client/url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.129%3A8081
```

Previously this was a different url like:

```
Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.129:8081
```

After it has changed to this long url, when trying open the iOS simulator, i get this error:

```
› Opening on iOS...
› Opening exp+jorato://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.129%3A8081 on iPhone 13
Device iPhone 13 (B7D52679-208F-49F2-8FF6-9E2CC4A47073) has no app to handle the URI: exp+jorato://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.129%3A8081
```

"jorato" comes from my app.json setting frome "scheme" under "expo":

```
"expo": {
    "name": "Jorato",
    "slug": "jorato",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "jorato",
    ...
```

I've been searching for documentation of where this url comes from with no luck. Anyone who could point me in right direction would be much appreciated.

Update: Found https://docs.expo.dev/development/development-workflows/, which defines that deep links use:

```
{scheme}://expo-development-client/?url={manifestUrl}

URL scheme of your client (defaults to exp+{slug} where slug is the value set in your app.json)
```

This seems consistent with what i'm getting. So must be something else that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that combined with the knowledge gained here https://docs.expo.dev/development/development-workflows/ that the problem is related to having a prior ios build and then that being deleted but not being done correctly. I've made a new build and am no longer getting this issue. Not completely sure what the reason was.

Comment: Same boat. 2nd time I've tried this build. Nothing installed on the simulator.

Comment: Check if you still have "expo-dev-client" in your package.json